# JavaScript regex global flag doesn't return all occurences

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a binary representation of a decimal:

```
1000010001
```

I want to match a sequence of consecutive zeros that is surrounded by ones at both ends, `10001`.

So in my string there are two such occurrences:

```
100001
10001
```

But for some reason `match` with `g` returns only the first:

```
'1000010001'.match(/(?:10+1)+/ig)
> ["100001"]
```

Why not both? How to make it return all occurrences?

Comment: The first match "consumes" the second `1` digit. You could back up the regex by 1 after each match if you did the matching in a loop.

Comment: There is a dupe for this somewhere. I'm searching.... Bottom line is: when `100001` is matched, what left in the string is `0001` so applying the regex on the rest won't match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matches consume characters, so after the first match, the string becomes `0001` and thus doesn't match the pattern anymore; You can turn the second `1` in the pattern into a *look ahead* assertion which doesn't consume characters, then add `1` to each match later:

```js
var s = '1000010001';

console.log(
  s.match(/10+(?=1)/g).map(x => x + '1')
)
```